# Error in skipping command in transactional replication in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

My transactional replication is failing continuously. I am trying to skip the command but not able to do that. Below are the steps which I performed.

1) use distribution

```
select * from MSrepl_commands where xact_seqno=0x003A16D800003FF0000600000000 and command_id=6
```

2) Now, on subscriber I ran this command

```
USE subscriber_db
GO

sp_setsubscriptionxactseqno  'publisher', 'publisher_db', 'publication_name', 0x003A16D800003FF0000600000000
```

I am getting this error

> Msg 14135, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_setsubscriptionxactseqno, Line 142
>   There is no subscription on Publisher 'UBNRDB15', publisher database 'Unibet_affiliate', publication 'Test Player Replication'

Anybody please let me know how to solve this? Or any other way I can skip that command?

Comment: Is it a push or pull subscription?  Use [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190493(v=sql.105).aspx) to confirm your subscription is set up correctly.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide it is push subscription

Comment: use sp_helpsubscription to check your subscription is set up correctly.